# How to post a reply to a Team Discussion thread using webservice?

Tags: web-services, sharepoint, mime

I'm trying to post a reply in a Team Discussion in SharePoint using the [Lists webservice](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists_members(v=office.12).aspx). I have tried the `AddDiscussionBoardItem` operation. Since the message parameter should be MIME, I create the thread by posting a message like:

```
Message-ID: <1343576290.0.1409922592343.JavaMail.foouser@foocomputer>
Subject: Test thread
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Thread-Index: Ac/JCq4D1Jh6s4l1SLGY/7pz8XIN2Q==

Body of test thread.
```

This works. But then I try to create a reply. Note the Thread-Index which is required according the webservice specification.

```
Message-ID: <1708591960.0.1409922780765.JavaMail.foouser@foocomputer>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Thread-Index: Ac/JCq4D1Jh6s4l1SLGY/7pz8XIN2QAAHBNL

Body of thread reply.
```

This gets posted, but instead of ending up as a reply, a new thread named "(no title)" is created. I thought the Thread-Index was the key, I have tried to implement it according [ConversationIndex Property specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee202481(v=exchg.80).aspx). To sum it up, the first 22 bytes (unencoded) should be same in the thread, with an extra 5 bytes extra for every level down. (An odd thing is that you post it base64-encoded, but get it back in hex.)

So, what's missing or is there another way of doing it?

I'm programming in Java but I don't think the challenge is language-specific.

Comment: Have you been able to generate the ThreadIndex ?